# Android: ActionBar is overlayed by camera image

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, metaio

I am using Metaio SDK 5.5 on the Epson Moverio BT200 (Android 4.0, API 15) and ran into a problem in one of my activities: The action bar is not visible on the device but it appears on screenshots which were taken via `adb`. The problematic activity inherits `com.metaio.sdk.ARViewActivity`.

After a few tests, I came to the conclusion that it can be fixed by changing the style. I want to use `android:Theme.Holo` as parent (which seems to be the default style on the device) but then the action bar is invisible. However, if I use `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` as parent style the action bar is visible but the app is too bright.

Is there an easy way to show the action bar? For the time being, I changed the style to `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` and began to restyle the UI components which I need to look like the theme I originally planned to use.

This question was posted on the [Metaio Helpdesk](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/35385/action-bar-invisible) as well.

Comment: Could you just create your own theme?

Comment: @323go That's what I'm doing more or less. At least for the components I plan on using.

Comment: Create an entire theme; you can inherit from your preferred theme -- this will allow you to quickly modify the entire app, if necessary.